# Angular - Wait for .Run finish all the pending async requests

Tags: angularjs

My app had this .run

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $http) {
    $rootScope.server = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/rawDemo";
    var call = $rootScope.server + "/frontEnd/GetStructure";
    var texts = {};
    texts.languages = {};
    $http.get(call).then(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.languages.length; i++) {
            texts.languages[response.data.languages[i].iso2] = {
                'title': response.data.languages[i].title,
                'description': response.data.languages[i].description,
                'keywords': response.data.languages[i].keywords,
                'frontEndTexts': response.data.languages[i].frontEndTexts
            };
        }
        $rootScope.texts = texts;
        $rootScope.webshop = response.data;
        $rootScope.webshop.language = response.data.culture.language;
        $rootScope.webshop.numberFormat = "";
        $rootScope.carouselData = response.data.frontEndConfig.customConfiguration.mjCarousel;
        console.log('end run');
    });
})
```

.And some of my resolvers perform a call in a service...

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('Products',['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope){
    return {
        listByCategories : function (categories){
            console.log('begin service');
            var call = $rootScope.server + '/products/list/categories/' + categories.fullPath +'?page1&recordsPerPage=2' ;
                return $http.get(call).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    }
}])
```

My expected result in console.log supposed to be:
- end run
- begin service

but instead..begin service starts before the end run. It's because the .run finish and keep the $http executing asynchronously and go on to the next stages like resolvers, for example.

According to my research on this website, it's impossible to make the $http works synchronous. So, my question is...any hint about how to handle the scenario ? My service depends from data that's must be loaded before anything.

I cannot "merge" the .run and the service because all the others views, services, must have the .run executed before. in my .run I load dozen of global configurations basically.

**UPDATE : I'm still stucked...but I'm  trying something...I changed the way I'm doing the things..**

so, on my .run

```
$rootScope.loadWebshop = function(callBack) {
        if($rootScope.loaded) { return ; }
        var call = $rootScope.server + "/frontEnd/GetStructure";
        var texts = {};
        texts.languages = {};
        $http.get(call).then(function (response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.languages.length; i++) {
                texts.languages[response.data.languages[i].iso2] = {
                    'title': response.data.languages[i].title,
                    'description': response.data.languages[i].description,
                    'keywords': response.data.languages[i].keywords,
                    'frontEndTexts': response.data.languages[i].frontEndTexts
                };
            }
            $rootScope.texts = texts;
            $rootScope.webshop = response.data;
            $rootScope.webshop.language = response.data.culture.language;
            $rootScope.webshop.numberFormat = "";
            $rootScope.carouselData = response.data.frontEndConfig.customConfiguration.mjCarousel;
            $rootScope.loaded = true;
            console.log('end .run');
            callBack();
        });
    }
```

..And on my service :

```
 listByCategories : function (categories){
            return $rootScope.loadWebshop (function () {
                console.log('begin service');
                var call = $rootScope.server + '/products/list/categories/' + categories.fullPath +'?page1&recordsPerPage=2' ;
                return $http.get(call).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            });
        }
```

Now I'm facing a different issue...it's returns undefined because it's asyncronous, even using premise. Any clue ??